# Spawn в Additive Scene

Tags: unity3d

В моей игре есть Master сцена и пара Slave. В Slave находится SpawnManager, но он добавляет объекты в Master сцену.

Есть ли способ заставить Юнити добавлять объекты в ту же сцену в которой находится SpawnManager?

Comment: Активная сцена влияет только то, где создаются новые объекты и на настройки света. Просто сделайте сцену со спавнером изначально активной и все.

Comment: У меня две сцены со спавнерами которые должны работать асинхронно. Я могу сделать активной одну сцену, но это не решает эту же проблему во второй. Если я вас правильно понял, конечно.

Comment: Тогда никак, аддитивные сцены предназначены не для этого. Вы уверены, что вы не можете разместить все спавнеры в одной сцене?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена!

Решение:

SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(Instantiate(name),SceneManager.GetSceneByBuildIndex(sceneIndex));

Используя SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene мы можем добавлять объекты в определенную сцену.